# What's a jQuery Music Player that loads songs from a mysql database?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm looking for a jQuery Music Player that loads songs from a mysql database using php. I could use a plugin, but I would prefer a tutorial that teaches me how to do it, so I can customize the music player.

Does anyone know a jQuery Music Player that loads songs from a mysql database or a tutorial that teaches how to do it?

Comment: If you want to create a music player that works in all browsers, you're going to have to use flash or some other kind of plugin.

Comment: Quick google search found this http://www.jplayer.org/. But I have no idea how it works or whether or not are there any tutorials

Comment: Most of the players use flash if default support is not available. So look for generic players rather than **jQuery**. You will get wider option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use jPlayer all the time to get songs from a MySQL database. You're going to have to write a back end script that loads the song in to the player though. It seems like you might be storing the song files directly into the database. If I were you, I would store the files in another location, store the URL in the database and plug it in to jPlayer like so:

```
$(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
   mp3: "<?php echo $path_to_music_file; ?>"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try JW Player with this jQuery plugin : http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jwplayer

or flowplayer with jQuery : http://flowplayer.org/plugins/index.html

both of them are good. but flowplayer gives you more freedom as it is open source.

Comment: Do either one of those load their playlist from a mysql database? I can't any reference to that on either of those pages.

Comment: zeckdude, Yes they can load their playlist from a script ( be it php,modpython,perl etc) . The script fetches the data from MySQL database and creates an XML which is used by the player. So have a PHP script to fetch data from mysql and create  an xml to feed to the player.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some player.
http://www.jplayer.org/latest/demos/

I would like to recommand you to use jquery song manager. under following link.
it quite easy to customize.
http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/