# How do I create a directory path on PHP

Tags: php, mysql, audio, web, xampp

I have created a database on phpmyadmin via xampp. I'm currently trying to make a music player and I am having difficulty linking my music folder to my php coding. I don't know the right syntax or the location I should be working on either within my coding to implement the music player.

[This is how my php translate currently and if you look at the Play column, it references the audio file's name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FI42U.png)

[And this is where all my music is stored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpcbC.png)

Someone please help me, please..1

Here's my coding as well

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
     border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "jukebox";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$sql = "SELECT * FROM Music";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo "<table>

     <tr>

     <th>Artist</th>
     <th>Title</th>
     <th>Album</th>
     <th>Albumcover</th>
     <th>Play</th>
     </tr>";

// output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

         echo 

         "<tr>

         <td>" . $row["Artist"]. "</td>
         <td>" . $row["Title"]. "</td>
         <td>" . $row["Album"]. "</td>
         <td><img src='/jukebox/img/" . $row["Albumcover"] ."' alt=".$row["Albumcover"]."></td>
         <td>" . $row["Play"]  . "></td>



         </tr>";
     }
     echo "</table>";



} else {
     echo "0 results";
}



?>  


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're going to create a music player with your list of musics, is that correct? That would be, I think, a plenty of work to do. You must have a working css, jquery, plugin and whatever that helps. Have a look at this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102137/whats-a-jquery-music-player-that-loads-songs-from-a-mysql-database]

Answer (score 0):

```
<td>
  <img src='"<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; ?>"'/jukebox/img/" . $row["Albumcover"] ."' alt=".$row["Albumcover"].">
</td>
```

try this one

Comment: thank you for responding, i need help with creating a directory for my music though not the images atm, do you know how to do that?

Comment: mkdir(path/new_folder_name, 0777, true);  try thid